# Relative roundoff error in the simple precision.

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-arithmetic

I am struggling with a simple problem from the computer arithmetics. The goal is to find $|(fl(0.1)-0.1)/0.1|$. I have computed the binary representation of $0.1$, which is $(1.1001)_{2}\times2^{-4}$, where the $1001$ after the decimal point is periodic. I know that $fl(0.1)$ is rounding the $0.1$ up, so we get $(1.1001...101)_{2}\times2^{-4}$, where the last digit is on the $-23$rd position. But I don't know how to compute the relative error. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I edited

Answer (score 1):

Just plug into the formula.  You have $fl(0.1)$ and $0.1$ so now subtract.  Starting from the last position in your $fl(0.1)$ the true value continues $011\ 001\ 100\ldots$ so if we subtract we get (about) $001$ with the first $0$ matching the last $1$ in $fl(0.1)$.  That is $22$ places to the right of the radix point, so the difference is $2^{-4}\cdot 2^{-22}\cdot 2^{-2}=2^{-28}$ where the first factor is from the exponent of $fl(0.1)$, the second is from all the places to the right of the radix point, and the third is the two places the $1$ in the error is to the right of the end of $fl(0.1)$.  The relative error is then $\frac {2^{-28}}{0.1}\approx 3.7\cdot 10^{-8}$

If you want the exact answer, you need the exact value of $fl(0.1)$.  I asked [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.1001100110011001100101%20base%202) and got $\frac {6710885}{16\cdot4194304}$.  Then the [relative error](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10*(6710885%2F16%2F4194304-1%2F10)) is $10(\frac {6710885}{16\cdot4194304}-\frac 1{10})=-\frac 7{33554432}$

Comment: I have a slightly different answer

Comment: For the absolute error I get 1/10×2^(-26)

Comment: And relative is therefore 2^(-26)

Comment: My computation of $fl(0.1)-0.1$ was not exact.  Usually we are only interested in the magnitude of errors like this.  $2^{-26}$ is not correct because that is the whole value of the last $1$ in your expression, but $0.1$ is greater than your expression with the last $1$ changed to a $0$.

Comment: Well, not in this case. The question is about the precise value. Thank you anyway

Comment: I have to be able to compute it by hand

Comment: Which is not hard, just tidious. I was wandering if someone knew some good way how to do it

Comment: It's good to see that a truncated number has difference which is its own power

Comment: And then exploit it in the computation

Comment: Getting that many digits by hand will be a lot of work.  You have to find the difference $fl(0.1)-0.1$ in binary, which will have a repeat of four bits, multiply by $16$ and subtract to get rid of the repeating part.  That will give the answer Alpha gave.

Comment: I think this is a terrible problem to ask for an exact hand solution.  It would be reasonable to bound the absolute error by $2^{-26}$ and ask what relative error that is.  The fact is that the relative error of a $32$ bit float is always about $2^{-23}$ because you have $23$ bits.  That is useful intuition, but finding the exact error of any number is silly.